# Crear una ventana con un JTextPane y un JMenuBar para modificar aspectos de texto

Tags: java

estoy intentando que me funcione un ejercicio simple en el que quiero crear una ventana con un JTextPane y un JMenuBar para modificar aspectos de todo el texto dentro del JTextPane (no solo el seleccionado) como tamaño, negrita o fuente.
Quiero que los cambios que le vaya haciendo al texto, como por ejemplo, ponerlo en negrita, se vayan acumulando a los siguientes cambios según voy tocando los ítems del JMenuBar.
Para ello he creado una clase en la que paso por parámetros del constructor las 3 variables de setFont. También he creado otras 3 variables en la clase principal para guardar los parámetros del constructor y que así los cambios que le hago al formato del texto se vayan acumulando. El problema lo tengo en este punto, no consigo que se me guarden los cambios en estas variables.

```
package graficosyventanas;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ejercicio_practico__procesador_texto {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        marq.setBounds(150,150,1000,450);
        marq.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marq.add(lam);
        lam.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        lam.add(mibarra, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        lam.add(texto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mibarra.add(fuente);
        mibarra.add(estilo);
        mibarra.add(tamanio);

        agrex fuente1 = new ejercicio_practico__procesador_texto().new agrex("Verdana", est, tam, fuente,"Verdana");
        agrex estilo1 = new ejercicio_practico__procesador_texto().new agrex(fu, Font.BOLD, tam, estilo,"Negrita");
        agrex estilo2 = new ejercicio_practico__procesador_texto().new agrex(fu, Font.PLAIN, tam, estilo,"Normal");
        agrex fuente2 = new ejercicio_practico__procesador_texto().new agrex("Calibri", est, tam, fuente,"Calibri");

        marq.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JFrame marq = new JFrame();

    private static JMenuBar mibarra = new JMenuBar();
    private static JTextPane texto = new JTextPane();
    private static JPanel lam = new JPanel();
    private static JMenu fuente = new JMenu("Fuente");
    private static JMenu tamanio = new JMenu("Tamaño");
    private static JMenu estilo = new JMenu("Estilo");

    private static String fu="Arial";  //las 3 variables para que se me acumulen los cambios de formato del texto
    private static int est=Font.PLAIN;
    private static int tam=12;

    private static agrex tamanio1 = new ejercicio_practico__procesador_texto().new agrex(fu, est, 20, tamanio,"20");

    private class agrex {
            public agrex(String fuent, int estil, int taman, JMenu x,String titulo){

                JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(titulo);
                x.add(item);
                item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        //clase interna anónima

                        texto.setFont(new Font(fuent,estil,taman));
                        tam=taman;
                        est=estil;
                        fu=fuent;
                        System.out.print(fu + ", ");
                        System.out.print(est + ", ");
                        System.out.println(tam);
                    }
                });
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

aqui acomode un poco tu codigo de forma que pudieras almacenar los valores, cambie la clase Agrex para que herede del JMenuItem y asi agregar los nuevos atributos, al agregarlos al menu, cada item mantendra los valores que enviaste en el contructor.

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        marq.setBounds(150,150,1000,450);
        marq.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marq.add(lam);
        lam.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        lam.add(mibarra, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        lam.add(texto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mibarra.add(fuente);
        mibarra.add(estilo);
        mibarra.add(tamanio);

        test.Agrex fuente1 = new test.Agrex(fuente, texto, "Verdana", "Verdana", est, tam);
        test.Agrex estilo1 = new test.Agrex(estilo, texto,"Negrita","Negrita", est, tam);

        marq.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JFrame marq = new JFrame();

    private static JMenuBar mibarra = new JMenuBar();
    private static JTextPane texto = new JTextPane();
    private static JPanel lam = new JPanel();
    private static JMenu fuente = new JMenu("Fuente");
    private static JMenu tamanio = new JMenu("Tamaño");
    private static JMenu estilo = new JMenu("Estilo");

    private static String fu="Arial";  //las 3 variables para que se me acumulen los cambios de formato del texto
    private static int est=Font.PLAIN;
    private static int tam=12;

    private static class Agrex extends JMenuItem{
    private String fuente;
    private int estilo, tamano;
    private JTextPane pane;

    public Agrex(JMenu menu, JTextPane pane, String titulo, String fuente, int estilo, int tamano){
        super(titulo);

        this.pane = pane;
        this.fuente = fuente;
        this.estilo = estilo;
        this.tamano = tamano;
        menu.add(this);

        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Agrex agrex = (Agrex)e.getSource();
                System.out.println("agrex: " + agrex.fuente);
                agrex.pane.setFont(new Font(agrex.fuente, agrex.estilo, agrex.tamano));
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```